# Three-way comparing strings in Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Say you want to optimize a (byte) string compare intensive algorithm implemented in Python. Since a central code path contains this sequence of statements

```
if s < t:
    # less than ...
elif t < s:
    # greater than ...
else:
    # equal ...
```

it would be great to optimize it to something like

```
r = bytes_compare(s, t)
if r < 0:
    # less than ...
elif r > 0:
    # greater than ...
else:
    # equal ...
```

where (the hypothetical) `bytes_compare()` ideally would just call the [three-way comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison) C function [`memcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcmp) which is usually quite well optimized. This would reduce the number of string comparisons by half. A very feasible optimization unless the strings are ultra short.

But how to get there with Python 3?

**PS**:

Python 3 has removed the three way comparison global function `cmp()` and the magic method `__cmp__()`. And even with Python 2, the `bytes` class doesn't had a  `__cmp__()` member.

With the `ctypes` package it's straight forward to call `memcmp()` but the foreign function call overhead with `ctypes` is prohibitively high.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing string comparisons in a loop in Python.  That will always be slow.  You'd be better off engineering a proper fast solution using related tools like Cython, Pandas, etc.  But doing that will require a holistic look at the surrounding code, not microbenchmarking a single string comparison.

Comment: How is `s < t` comparison implemented atm, given that `s` and `t` are `bytes`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck, well, I did some profiling with pyflame and this verified that a significant amount of time is spend in these paired comparisons (`s` with `t` followed by `t` with `s`). Note that this pattern isn't unusual - for example, you also have this when you merge/join 2 sorted sequences of strings. Also, Python string comparison aren't slow in general - if you just need one comparison outcome for a pair `s` and `t` then they are fast, as is. Thus, this really isn't about isolated microbenchmarking.

Comment: @urban, with Python 3.6.5, there is `Objects/bytesobject.c` and it calls `memcmp()` in `bytes_compare_eq()` and `bytes_richcompare()` (for `<` or `>`).

Comment: From https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/49779 where they discuss `cmp()` in python 3, the suggested way is to do: `((a > b) - (b > a))`. This will give you the `r` but ... it is still 2 comparisons. I have tried a python-based implementation of `bytes_compare`... very bad idea :) at least 3x slower

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 3 (including 3.6) simply doesn't include any three-way comparison support for strings. Although the internal implementation of the rich comparison operator `__lt__()`, `__eq__()` etc. do call `memcmp()` (in the C implementation of `bytes` - cf. `Objects/bytesobject.c`) there is no internal three-way comparison function that could be leveraged.

Thus, writing a [C extension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/extending.html) that provides a three-way comparison function by calling `memcmp()` is the next best thing:

```
#include <Python.h>
static PyObject* cmp(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
    PyObject *a = 0, *b = 0;
    if (!PyArg_UnpackTuple(args, "cmp", 2, 2, &a, &b))
        return 0;
    if (!PyBytes_Check(a) || !PyBytes_Check(b)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "only bytes() strings supported");
        return 0;
    }
    Py_ssize_t n = PyBytes_GET_SIZE(a), m = PyBytes_GET_SIZE(b);
    char *s = PyBytes_AsString(a), *t = PyBytes_AsString(b);
    int r = 0;
    if (n == m) {
        r = memcmp(s, t, n);
    } else if (n < m) {
        r = memcmp(s, t, n);
        if (!r)
            r = -1;
    } else {
        r = memcmp(s, t, m);
        if (!r)
            r = 1;
    }
    return PyLong_FromLong(r);
}
static PyMethodDef bytes_util_methods[] = {
    { "cmp", cmp, METH_VARARGS, "Three way compare 2 bytes() objects." },
    {0,0,0,0} };
static struct PyModuleDef bytes_util_def = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, "bytes_util", "Three way comparison for strings.",
    -1, bytes_util_methods };
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_bytes_util(void) {
    Py_Initialize();
    return PyModule_Create(&bytes_util_def);
}
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -Wall -O3 -fPIC -shared bytes_util.c -o bytes_util.so -I/usr/include/python3.6m
```

Test:

```
>>> import bytes_util
>>> bytes_util.cmp(b'foo', b'barx')
265725
```

In contrast to calling `memcmp` via the `ctypes` package, this foreign call has the same overhead as the builtin bytes comparison operators (as they also are implemented as C extension with the standard Python version).

Comment: Note: To make this significantly more reusable with near zero overhead, replacing explicit use of the `PyBytes` APIs with the more general buffer interface ([`PyObject_GetBuffer`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#c.PyObject_GetBuffer) with `flags` `PyBUF_SIMPLE`) would allow this to work seamlessly with `bytearray`, `mmap`, `array.array('B')`, and all manner of other `bytes`-like objects. You'd just declare a pair of `Py_buffer` structures on the stack, populate them w/`PyObject_GetBuffer` and your inputs, then use `buf.buf` and `buf.len` where you currently use `s/t` and `m/n`.